# JWT Authentication for laravel built api for mobile application

Tags: android, laravel, jwt

I have to build an API for a mobile application.

I see Laravel would be a good choice to develop the api.

What concerns me is the Authentication part.

For me OAuth seems to be difficult to implement.

Would JWT be a good idea? Would it be secure enough for a mobile App ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JWT alone might not be secure enought depending on your app needs.
Anyway, I think you are going the right way by using JWT.

To maximize security always use ssl encription and if you are really concerned about priacy read about Jason Web Encription JWE.

Anyway JWT is probably the best way to go, it makes it much easier to handle Authentication and Authoritzation on mobile devices and simplifies the process of making AJAX requests to your API.

Hope it helps,